# Joomla 4 - user fields in activation email

Tags: user-registration

After registration of a new user in the front-end, verification and activation emails are sent.

However, my registration form uses user fields and I would like to include them in these emails.

These emails can be easily updated via language overrides but I can't figure out how to add these user fields to the language overrides.

In these language overrides, standard Joomla elements are shown as eg. {USERNAME}.
But how can a user field, eg. “contact”, be included?

Comment: Are you using the User-Profile plugin to add your additional fields or a 3rd party extension?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: with Acymailing you can easily override the registration emails. A bit overkill if you do not need Acymailing, luckily, I was already using it.

Another solution is also possible, but is a bit more cumbersome: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=1000525

Custom fields are powerful but not really developed nor user-friendly for end users.